# Getting full file path of a clients file using a file dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to allow users to upload pictures to the server.

I am trying to create a similar system to any website that has an 'attach' file or 'upload image' feature. All I need is to get the full path of the file select by the file dialog.

I tried using this for the file dialog with no success:

```
<input type="file">
```

This method does not provide the full file path, due to security reasons. My question is how can I create a similar input dialog to websites like tinypic, photobucket, etc.. that can help users input the full file path of a given image, into an input field?

I am aware that this cannot be done using the method above for security reasons, however, I have seen this done before on various websites without any problems, I was wondering what I had to do to implement a similar file dialog that helps fill in the text, which is a full file path, of an input field?

Comment: Are you trying to read the files locally?

Comment: Why would you ever need the full path?

Comment: I suspect it's possible with Flash but not with a pure JavaScript solution.

Comment: No it is not possible to get the full path of the file. Why do you need it anyway? I hope you are aware that file can be read the file even without having full path....

Comment: I need the full file path for the same reasons that websites like photobucket and tinypic need the full file path... I need server-side access to the clients file. @closure, There is no question whether or not it is possible, it IS possible (see photobucket, tinypic, etc.. for proof), I am just not sure how to implement it.

Comment: @MHZ the file name that is displayed besides the file selection button are not done by the program. It is part of the file element display to which javascript has no access.

Comment: @MHZ, still pending from your side: why do you need the full path?

Comment: I need to copy images from the source (client) to the destination (server), using PHP's copy function that takes in two values.... copy(<source>,<destination>).

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Just completed looking at code I have and surfing the possibilities for you. It is just not possible to get the full path. I am posting answer on normal methods of uploading files to server.

Comment: Tell you what. Why don't you first give the copy function a try. Just hard code the _full path_ of a known image file (on your desktop for example) into the copy function and see it it works. Make sure that you test the script on a _real_ server, not on your local.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It is not possible to get the file full path on local machine using browser and javascript.**

However, as you would like to upload the file to the server, the easy possibility I see is to use html form with `input type file`. You will receive the file on your http server when the form is submitted.

Here is a very good url http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/file.html that explains the whole process nicely.